# CollectionView - Release memory of UIImageViews from custom CollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uiimage

I have a collectionView that I did programatically, in which I have four cell types and each contains an image.

I alternate this cells by the indexPath.item.

I want them to be released from memory when I pass through the cells in order to save memory.

With the current code the cell images are allocated in memory and are only released when I exit this ViewController, but I want them to be deallocated in the CollectionView.

I saw that it could be due to UIImage (named :) so I switched to UIImage (contentOfFile), but it continued in that way.

The closest I could do was to declare a global UIImageView and move to the cells, where inside each cell I save a weak var to this UIImageView, but the images do not appear and only the texts remain.

Would anyone know how I could free up the memory of each cell's images while the user scrolls the collectionview?

Bellow the code:

```
import UIKit

class Gallery_ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout 
{


lazy var galleryCollection: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout:     collectionLayout)
}()

var imageView = UIImageView()

let paths: [String] = [Bundle.main.path(forResource: “img1", ofType: "png", inDirectory: "Images")!,
    Bundle.main.path(forResource: “img2", ofType: "png", inDirectory: "Images")!,
    Bundle.main.path(forResource: “img3", ofType: "png", inDirectory: "Images")!,
    Bundle.main.path(forResource: “img4”, ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Images")!]

// Called before showing the view
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup()
}

/// Setup
func setup() {
    setup_views()
}


/// Setup views
func setup_views() {



    galleryCollection.dataSource = self
    galleryCollection.delegate = self
    galleryCollection.isPagingEnabled = true
    galleryCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    galleryCollection.register(Gallery_1_Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: “GalleryCell_1")
    galleryCollection.register(Gallery_2_Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: “GalleryCell_2”)
    galleryCollection.register(Gallery_3_Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: “GalleryCell_3")
    galleryCollection.register(Gallery_Final_Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: “GalleryCell_Final")


    view.addSubview(galleryCollection)



    //      apperance
    galleryCollection.backgroundColor = .white

    //      constraints
    galleryCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: galleryCollection, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view, attribute: .centerX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: galleryCollection, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view, attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: galleryCollection, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view, attribute: .width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: galleryCollection, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view, attribute: .height,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))


}


// Returning Number of Cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}


    // Returning Cells
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    print("Index: \(indexPath.item)")
    print("Index Row: \(indexPath.row)")

    //let imageV = UIImageView()
    //imageView = imageV
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        print("0000")
        // creating cell
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCell_1", for: indexPath) as? Gallery_1_Cell




        cell?.stringImagem = paths[indexPath.item]
        cell?.imagem = UIImage(contentsOfFile: paths[indexPath.item])
        cell?.backgroundImage = imageView
        // passing collection view
        //cell.backgroundImage = imageView
        cell?.parentDelegate = self


        // set custom apperance
        cell?.setCustomApperance()

        return cell!
    }

    if indexPath.item == 1 {

        // creating cell
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCell_2”, for: indexPath) as? Gallery_2_Cell


        print("1111")


        cell?.stringImagem = paths[indexPath.item]
        cell?.imagem = UIImage(contentsOfFile: paths[indexPath.item])
        cell?.backgroundImage = imageView

        // passing collection view
        //cell.backgroundImage = imageView
        cell?.parentDelegate = self


        // set custom apperance
        cell?.setCustomApperance()

        return cell!
    }

    if indexPath.item == 2 {

        // creating cell
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCell_3”, for: indexPath) as? Gallery_3_Cell

        print("2222")

        cell?.stringImagem = paths[indexPath.item]
        cell?.imagem = UIImage(contentsOfFile: paths[indexPath.item])
        cell?.backgroundImage = imageView

        // passing collection view

        cell?.parentDelegate = self


        // set custom apperance
        cell?.setCustomApperance()

        return cell!
    }

    if indexPath.item == 3 {

        // creating cell
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GalleryCell_Final", for: indexPath) as? Gallery_Final_Cell


        print("3333")

        cell?.stringImagem = paths[indexPath.item]
        cell?.imagem = UIImage(contentsOfFile: paths[indexPath.item])
        cell?.backgroundImage = imageView

        // pass delegate
        //cell.backgroundImage = imageView
        cell?.parentDelegate = self


        // set custom apperance
        cell?.setCustomApperance()

        return cell!
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



}

// Returning Cells Size
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}


// Setting the Space between lines
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}


// Setting the Inter Space between lines
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}





}
```

Below is the cell model I use, it's pretty much the same in the four cases, so I'll only put one.

```
import UIKit

class Gallery_1_Cell: UICollectionViewCell 
{



// views
var backgroundImage: UIImageView?

weak var imagem : UIImage?

var stringImagem:String?



// Initializer
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

}


// Serializer
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func prepareForReuse() {
    print("Cell1")
//       self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    for v in self.subviews{
        print("Cell1 Removeu")
        print("V: \(v)")
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}


/// Setup
func setup() {
    setup_views()
    setup_proportionalFonts()
}


/// Setup views
func setup_views() {

    // Main View
    self.clipsToBounds = true


    // Background Image
    let im = UIImage(contentsOfFile: stringImagem!)
    backgroundImage?.image = im
    self.addSubview(backgroundImage!)

    //      apperance
    backgroundImage?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    backgroundImage?.backgroundColor = .red

    //      constraints
    backgroundImage?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: backgroundImage!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self, attribute: .centerX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: backgroundImage!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self, attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: backgroundImage!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self, attribute: .width,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: backgroundImage!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: self, attribute: .height,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0))




/// Set Custom Apperance
func setCustomApperance() {
    setup()

}



}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do... you say you want images released from memory when you *"pass through the cells"*? What do you mean by that? And *"while the user scrolls the collectionview"*? The cells are reused when the user scrolls, so memory management is handled automatically.

Comment: My collectionview has 4 cells, I want to scroll from one cell to another and it only keep in memory the cell that I am.

Currently it keeps all in memory until I quit the viewcontroller that has this collectionView.

Comment: Well, if you have 4 cells... and the user can scroll through the cells... you will have at most only **one** cell not currently in use. Maybe scrollable collection view is not the ideal interface for you to use? (By the way... what makes you think you are taxing memory use with 4 images?)

Comment: If you want to achieve the effect of a working range with the collection view I would suggest you'd take a look at IGListKit (https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit).